# Mallet is not recognized as internal or external command

Tags: java, mallet

I am using windows 7.  I installed Mallet and it works perfectly when I go to the Mallet directory.  However, I am using some python software that calls it (https://github.com/uwgraphics/VEP_TMScripts) and I get the above referenced error.  How do I install it so it is accessible from my system path.  I tried to add it to the path and that did not work.. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Sincerely,

tom

Comment: Can you invoke malet with absolute path?

Comment: Hi Alex, Yes I can. Thank you for responding!

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not Windows user so I can't help you more :).

Comment: Actually when I just tried to run: C:\mallet\bin\mallet.bat import-dir --input sample-data\web\en --output tutorial.mallet --keep-sequence --remove-stopwords, I got the error "could not find or load main class cc.mallet.classify.tui. Text2Vectors

Answer (score 1):

For Windows you may need to set the environment variable %MALLET_HOME% to point to the MALLET directory in order for the `mallet.bat` command to work.

Calling Mallet from a python process might require you to set a classpath variable in Windows. You will need to check the script itself to be sure.

Comment: Hi David, Thank you for responding! I have a truly stupid question for you: How would I know that a classpath variable is required? Thank you!